# Hibernate LAZY fetching issue

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading

I have two classes Employee and Roles.Employee has many roles and each role has many Employees.
So that I have used ManyToMany relationship by taking another table 'EMPLOYEE_ROLES'.

In Employee class:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name="EMPLOYEE_ROLES",joinColumns=     {@JoinColumn(name="EC",nullable=false,updatable=false)},inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID", 
        nullable = false, updatable = false) }) 
public Set<Roles> getRolesList() {
    return rolesList;
}
```

and

In Roles class:

```
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade={CascadeType.ALL},mappedBy="rolesList")
public Set<Employee> getEmployees() {
    return employees;
}
```

But when I am fetching Employee And accessing roleList, roles are loaded perfectly but along with fetching delete query fired on EMPLOYEE_ROLES table.

```
 Employee ec=employeeService.findByEmployeeCode(121);
 Iterator<Roles> itr=ec.getRolesList().iterator();
```

Please can anyone suggest me. If I use `fetchType.EAGER` it works perfectly, but when I use LAZY,then only this problem comes:

```
 Hibernate: select roleslist0_.EC as EC11_1_, roleslist0_.ROLE_ID as ROLE2_41_1_, roles1_.ID as ID8_0_, roles1_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPT2_8_0_, roles1_.ROLES as ROLES8_0_ from EMPLOYEE_ROLES roleslist0_ inner join ENABLE.ROLES roles1_ on roleslist0_.ROLE_ID=roles1_.ID where roleslist0_.EC=?
 Hibernate: delete from EMPLOYEE_ROLES where EC=?
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's a bit unclear what your problem is: the `ec.getRolesList().iterator()` causes the `delete` command? I've seen this only with an update of the collection, usually followed by several `INSERT` statements to restore the elements of the collection. Are you sure you're not flushing the context after getting the iterator?

Comment: No ,the thing is whenever I do any operation on roleList ,I loads the data from database perfectly because of LAZY.but why the second query is fired?

Comment: The second query is probably fired by some other part of your code. What Hibernate version are you using and are you sure getting the Roles is the place where the delete is executed?

Comment: can someone please help me out whats wrong in mapping?

Comment: version 4.1.9 and at the time of fetching only the delete query is fired.

Answer (score 1):

Add @Transactional annotation on method where you call getters from LAZY fetch type. For example:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void doSomething(){
  ...
  Iterator<Roles> itr=ec.getRolesList().iterator();
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have cascade={CascadeType.ALL} on both the sides, try removing cascade on the role side.